# Objective-C with OpenSSL - Cannot set RSA Key

Tags: ios, objective-c, openssl

I am trying to use add RSA encryption to an app using OpenSSL, but I cannot get a certificate to load.  In my app, a public key certificate will be distributed from a server and I need to take that key and use it to decrypt content from encrypted barcodes that my app will scan.

The reason why I am choosing OpenSSL over the security library is that I also require ECDSA validation, which is currently unsupported natively.

I have tried numerous methods to get the key to load.  The OpenSSL PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY method requires a file pointer.  However when I run the code below, it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` as soon as I attempt to access the key.

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:  @"public" ofType: @"pem"];
FILE *f = fopen([path cStringUsingEncoding:1],"r");
if (f == NULL)
    NSLog(@"%@", [path stringByAppendingString:@" not found"]);

RSA *rsa = PEM_read_RSA_PUBKEY(f,NULL,NULL,NULL);

fclose(f);

NSLog (@"%d KeyCheck", RSA_check_key(rsa));
```

I have the included the following headers from the OpenSSL library

```
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
```

I have other OpenSSL methods such as MD5, Base64 encode/decode, SHA1 and the ECDSA code working OK, it's just passing in the RSA certificate that has got me stumped!

The public.pem key file contains this key:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC+ynZ7EvJ0F+IoGmlme/j/MpH4
7BxrIuDTJCOS99j82IL3Ww9Ubm28yOMHYPdi23WPDhR80ugaBWAnmqUZWvYKjqd4
Z4D0sJ0NVW3DDgZ4gS57zFqlvGgdVhzaVimfs7qDxIJ1o8GMuXWseZV2ZpmIjdnF
ZBol5zZTqNfk89RNnQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Your file must be started by -----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY----

Comment: Not sure that this is an issue since the command line `openssl rsautl -verify -in encrypted -out decrypted -inkey public.pem -pubin` works just fine with this key.

Comment: Just a dumb question: Have you verified that `path`, `f` and `rsa` are not NULL? - And note that the *proper* way would be `FILE *f = fopen([path fileSystemRepresentation],"r")` instead of a magic encoding number `1`.

Comment: `path` and `f` are valid and I can read the file contents in NSLog.  `rsa` is null which is what is causing the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program to read RSA public key is fine.

Problem is with

```
RSA_check_key
```

Please read about RSA_check_key [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_check_key.html).

It does not work on public key. You need private key for this function.
That is why it is crashing since it does have its private key.
Sorry for the inconvenience due to previous answers.

http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_check_key.html

Comment: I have changed the RSA key and tried `BIO *buffer = BIO_new_file([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "r");EVP_PKEY *key = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(buffer,NULL,NULL,NULL);` but `key` is still null.

Comment: Is it public key or public key certificate (X.509)?

Comment: I have edited for X.509 certificate. But after seeing its DER representation, it does not look like certificate. However, you can try if it works.

Comment: @PassKit: Read again. I got the cause.

Comment: Thanks for that, but this is still not the issue.  `rsa` is still null so if I try to use it for example with `RSA_public_decrypt(strlen(encrypted), (unsigned char *)encrypted, decrypted, cert, 1);` , it still crashes in the RSA_public_decrypt function at the point where it tries to access the key.

Comment: I tried your program in Windows, it runs fine with the same data. Means code to read public key is fine. Please check if the filename is valid and exists.

Comment: Yes, I now have it working - was a stupid error in that I was not base 64 decoding the string before trying to decrypt it, then in debugging, I used the `RSA_check_key` function and then Boom! This sent be on a wild goose chase for a problem that never existed! Your answer was spot on.  Thanks for taking the time to investigate.